# Using Else If statements UIPath

Tags: uipath, rpa, uipath-studio

Hie Devs i have attached one screen shoot for the pdf i have that contains a list of checkboxes under the section written “Package Selection” …so under this section a user ticks a particular package that they want e.g Basicare ,Private etc if there have other packages they write that package name on the section written Other (specify).Once i have extracted the package desired by the user i then select particular Insurer on the Health Information Platform(HIP) that correspond to the package name selected by the user.The insurer name is on the drop down menu on the top left corner on the attachement i have provided below which is the UI of the desktoipapplication.

So for all other packages that is Basicare,iCare,Private, Private Plus,MedExec Plus,Prime they belong to the Cimas USD insurer.
But if the user have written another package on the Other(specify) for example HEALTHGUARD option that package name will be mapped to the HEALTHGUARD insurer on Health Information Platform (HIP)

i have used the get full text activity and created a variable for this actvity a string variable and used the Else if statement with condtions

Comment: I cannot see a question or a PDF.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.